# How to change directions of the buttons in Bootstrap navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using **bootstrap-nav-wizard.css** for my project. Here is a demo:

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://acornejo.github.io/bootstrap-nav-wizard/bootstrap-nav-wizard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-wizard">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Step1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Step3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
</div>
</body>
```

The step buttons direction left to right.

I need to change the directions of the buttons from right to left.

I have this direction:

[image]

I want this direction:

[image]

My question is how I can change the direction of the buttons. What changes do I have to make in **bootstrap-nav-wizard.css** to change the directions of the buttons?

Comment: I think you have to customize the `css` used by `bootstrap-nav-wizard`

Comment: if you don't want text inside that than use `.nav-wizard { transform:rotate(180deg);}`

Comment: @ Amit singh, I have text inside if i make rotation the text will appear upside down

Answer (score 0):

Use the "pull-right" class in html tag of specific element.